# Error in file.read() return above 2 GB on 64 bit python

Tags: memory, python-2.7, large-files

I have several ~50 GB text files that I need to parse for specific contents. My files contents are organized in 4 line blocks. To perform this analysis I read in subsections of the file using file.read(chunk_size) and split into blocks of 4 then analyze them.

Because I run this script often, I've been optimizing and have tried varying the chunk size. I run 64 bit 2.7.1 python on OSX Lion on a computer with 16 GB RAM and I noticed that when I load chunks >= 2^31, instead of the expected text, I get large amounts of /x00 repeated. This continues as far as my testing has shown all the way to, and including 2^32, after which I once again get text. However, it seems that it's only returning as many characters as bytes have been added to the buffer above 4 GB.

My test code:

```
for i in range((2**31)-3, (2**31)+3)+range((2**32)-3, (2**32)+10):
    with open('mybigtextfile.txt', 'rU') as inf:
        print '%s\t%r'%(i, inf.read(i)[0:10])
```

My output:

```
2147483645  '@HWI-ST550'
2147483646  '@HWI-ST550'
2147483647  '@HWI-ST550'
2147483648  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
2147483649  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
2147483650  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967293  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967294  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967295  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967296  '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967297  '@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967298  '@H\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967299  '@HW\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967300  '@HWI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967301  '@HWI-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967302  '@HWI-S\x00\x00\x00\x00'
4294967303  '@HWI-ST\x00\x00\x00'
4294967304  '@HWI-ST5\x00\x00'
4294967305  '@HWI-ST55\x00'
```

What exactly is going on?

Comment: This might warrant opening a bug report in the CPython implementation. I don't have a system with that much RAM on my hands right now, so I cannot reproduce.

Comment: I'm not a Python hero, but it sounds like the type of the chunk_size parameter is 32-bit int, which will wrap to negative at 2**31. Furthermore, Python doesn't seem to have a way to force these values to unsigned. --- But does it pay to use such big chunk sizes? My tests in C++ indicate almost no speedup when using buffers larger than 256k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the known issue according to the comment in cpython's source code. You can check it in Modules/_io/fileio.c. And the code add a workaround on Microsoft windows 64bit only.